# How to check a valid csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file in this format

```
"emails"
"foo.bar@foo.com"
"bar.foo@foo.com"
"foobar@foo.com"
```

If a file is not in the above format, I want to throw a file format error. How to do this?

Comment: what *format* are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the csv module to read the file -- check the first row matches the header you expect, and use a regex (re module) to check the email addresses in subsequent lines...  Throw the appropriate exception or terminate the program if these measures fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just try [cutplace](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cutplace/) it validates if your csv conforms to a specified format.